# Batch file to rename folders goto command loop the rest of the code

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

I use a batch file to rename all folders with progressive numbers.

This code renames the folders well using loop function, but it loops the  rest of the code that contains echo and other commands.

The code to rename must finish until `:stop` and the batch file continue the execution without looping the rest of the code with other commands.

```
:: Rename Folders Code

@Echo off
Pushd "D:\Programmi Installati\" || (Echo couldn't change dir&pause&goto :stop)
set Cnt=0
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /B /AD log* ^| findstr /iV "^log_[0-9][0-9]*$" '
) Do Call :RenInc "%%A"
PopD    
Goto :stop

:RenInc
Set /A Cnt+=1
if Exist "log_%Cnt%" goto :RenInc
Ren "%~1" "log_%Cnt%"
)
:stop


:: Other Part Of Code, This Part Of Code Not Be looped

Echo "Hello"
Pause
Echo "Hello Hello"
Pause
Echo "Hello Hello Hello"
Pause
```

Comment: Please do **NOT** [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174672/batch-file-to-rename-folders-goto-command-loop-the-rest-of-the-code) You got the same answer there also. It **IS** easier to put called subroutines to the end of the batch file seperated by a `Goto :Eof` from main program flow, then it is not neccessary to jump around that code part.

Comment: You appear to have a mismatched paren under :RenInc:  on the line after Ren "%~1" "log_%Cnt%" you have ")".  Is that just a typo in the question itself?